# Regex for finding number of times substring "hello hello" occurs in string "hello hello hello"

Tags: regex, perl

I want to get the count of occurrence of a substring within a string.

My string is `"hello hello hello"`. I want to get the number of times `"hello hello"` occurs in it, which in the above case is **2**.
Can someone please help me find a regex for it?

Comment: How did you get **3** in your example?

Comment: Hello new user. I've edited your question and cleaned it up a little. I kept `3` in there, please edit it if it was a mistake, or explain it if it wasn't. Thanks, and welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: If that "3" does not get explained or corrected, I will vote for close in an hour...

Comment: It's either `2` or he meant to just count `hello`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on either you want to count the number of occurrence of `hello` (which is 3 in your example) or `hello hello` (wich is 2), you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use 5.10.1;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = q/hello hello hello/;
my $count1 =()= $str =~ /(?=\bhello hello\b)/g;
say $count1;  # gives 2

my $count2 =()= $str =~ /\bhello\b/g;
say $count2;  # gives 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(?=hello hello)
```

Using a lookahead lets you find overlapping results. For whole word only, you may try:

```
\b(?=hello hello\b)
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/om1xn1FmBI <sub><sup>the blue positions mark a match</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant "hello" and  not "hello hello" , you can just split on hello. No need to construct extra regex

```
$string="hello hello blah hello blah helloworld hello blah blah hello";
@s = split "hello", $string, -1;
print scalar @s - 1 ."\n"; #get size of array
```

Comment: Now, I'm no perl guy, but isn't `/hello/` a regex? In that case, you might as well match against it. Also, note that the question asks about `"hello hello"`, which suggests overlapping matches.

Comment: Note that /hello/ is a regex, though :-)

Comment: @Kobi: +1. While split can probably be done without a regex, overlapping would be a problem.

Comment: and note that question also says 3. Unless the OP redefines that, whether is overlapping or not is pure guess work

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for actually, [Counting the occurrences of a substring - the fastest way](http://www.chengfu.net/2005/10/count-occurrences-perl/).

Comment: That does not work for overlapping substrings though.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warning;
my $str = "hello hello hello bla bla hello bla hello";
my $count = grep /hello/ , split /\s+/,$str ;
print"$count"; #output 5
```

Comment: providing more `general solution` ie., first by splittig the string into words and then check by `grep` whether it is required word or not.

Comment: how is assuming that matching only needs to be done on word boundaries more general? (especially since "hello hello" is not one word)

Comment: yes that's true, but i am considering "hello" as one word unless OP explain it more and split string into words because assuming that string may contain words other than "hello".